# Toolbar and Tabs not appearing up with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, material-design

I am getting `Toolbar and Tabs`, If I would not use `ViewPager` :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

But when I use ViewPager, I am **not getting** Toolbar and Tabs

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: did you used LinearLayout ?

Comment: I am using same code as found in tutorial... I have not made any change

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: are you setting up the tablayout with viewpager in code?

Comment: Best Example for Material view :https://github.com/bsuhas/Android-Material-Design-for-pre-Lollipop

Comment: @Sun Go through http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your xml like this:

due to  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` this you are not able to view `ToolBar` & `Tabs`.

Here need to define `app:layout_behavior` for external view with `AppBarLayout` .

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: simply replace xml with yours it will works at my end.

Comment: what's different in it ?

Comment: app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to view pager matters.

Comment: yeah I got it. Thanks for info :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103718/discussion-between-sun-and-suhas-b).

Comment: which one is better library to implement Ripple Effect, this https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple or this one https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect